# How does Asus PC Link work?

Tags: asus-zenfone-5

I am using [Asus PC Link](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1007327) with my Asus Zenfone 5. It allows my to remotely connect to my Zenfone, in a way similar to RDP, but it only supports Windows Vista or higher, not Windows XP, Mac, or Linux.

I am wondering how Asus PC Link works and if there is a similar program/apps that can be used with Linux and other Android devices.

Comment: Based on the other answers, I surmise that the PC-side software must be using some custom functionality in the OS exposed only by the phone-side app when it is running (does not work if the app is open in background. must be in foreground). As of now, its functionality is unrivaled, by a large margin.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [link](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1007327) Asus PC does the following:

> ASUS PC Link lets you mirror your mobile device on your PC. It also allows you to control your Android device from your PC with the mouse and keyboard.

- I know of one app named [WebKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webkey)(libre software) which can remotely share your Android's screen to a computer (any platform). All you need to do is install this app, launch it (follow the instructions there) and once the service is started it will give you a URL. Type this URL into your browser (PC) and you're good to go.

  Note that this app hasn't been updated since Dec 2013, and so, recent Android versions might not support it.
- There is another method (I didn't try) called [Live Screencasting](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#screencasting). The instructions are mentioned at https://developer.chrome.com or you can click [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). Note that this option is supported for devices with Android 4.4.3 and above. (Alternative [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150513075803/https://gigaom.com/2013/10/08/how-to-screencast-an-android-device-to-chrome-or-chrome-os/) for easy instructions.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try [Live Screencasting](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#screencasting) :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome app called [vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm), it lets you control your phone from chrome browser itself. It only casts your device screen on the computer, and volume is not casted like Asus PC link.

Note: You need to turn of USB debugging to use this extension, no root is required.